# Call using a specific sim

Tags: android, kotlin

I was using a code to make calls using a specific sim on a J7 Prime, now I was trying on a more updated device, specifically an A12. The calling action is performed without problems, the problem is that the sim is not selected automatically. I would like to know if it is possible to update the code so that it selects the sim to call automatically.

```
if (services == "Giros Tigo") {
            getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.CALL")
            sendIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 0)
            sendIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra", true)
            sendIntent.putExtra("simSlot", 0)
            sendIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:*555*1*" + txtnumber.text.toString() + "*" + txtcedula.text.toString() + "*1*" + txtmonto.text.toString() + Uri.encode("#"))
            startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1)
                startActivity(intent)
                val cd: ClipboardManager =
                    getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                val clip = ClipData.newPlainText(
                    "AutoCopiado",
                    "*555*1*" + txtnumber.text.toString() + "*" + txtcedula.text.toString() + "*1*" + txtmonto.text.toString() + "#"
                )
                cd.setPrimaryClip(clip)
            }
```